# How does audio in OBS Studio work?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, obs-studio

Recently i've downloaded OBS Studio to attempt to figure it out. What i've noticed is it takes my desktop sound but doesn't play it through my headphones. It will register that sound is playing, but I can't hear anything. Once I close OBS, the sound is fine. I use Sony Bluetooth headphones model MDR-ZX770BN, and use stereo instead of hands-free. Is there any particular reason OBS Studio does this, and is there a way to hear the deskstop audio while OBS is open?

Comment: OBS or OBS Studio? Those are two different products.

Comment: My bad. Corrected the name to OBS Studio.

Comment: What audio drivers are installed in your computer?
You can try to record your desktop sound by enabling "Stereo Mix" in Recording devices, then select it in OBS studio.

Comment: It lists "Intel(R) Display Audio" and "Realtek High Definition Audio", though Realtek is what the default is.